# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency View Controller exception

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to change the detail view in a splitViewController, i have the UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception when i do
    self.detailView.view=view.view;
I've controlled if there are other viewControllers in xib files and i also used method removeFromParentViewController, but i've the same exception.
The error is only in iOS 6 but not in iOS 5, in iPad simulator.

Comment: Can you please provide some code to give context as to what's happening? Such as where does view.view come from, use of removeFromParentViewController, and the exact error spit out from Console.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! this is the error, view.view is the view i want to load in the splitViewController, there is no other code, i do only the change of the view in the split, i used removefromparentviewcontroller because i want to remove the association to the viewController to remove the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! this is the error, view.view is the view i want to load in the splitViewController, there is no other code, i do only the change of the view in the split, i used removefromparentviewcontroller because i want to remove the association to the viewController to remove the exception

Is your splitViewController an instance of UISplitViewController?
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

If so, you're doing something fundamentally wrong. The UISplitViewController is simply a container for two view controllers, a master view controller and a detail view controller. It is then up to your view controller to decide how to deal with interactions and such. removeFromParentViewController is only used in View Controller Containment, and as such doesn't seem applicable here.

Read the documentation in the link above to see if it meets your needs, but if I understand, you need to set your view **controllers** in the split view, not your views.

To do you, you need to do:

```
// Assume this is initialised correctly
UISplitViewController* splitViewController = [UISplitViewController alloc] init...];

// Assign the two view controller you want to be used in the split view controller
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterViewController, detailViewController];
```

If this isn't applicable, then please provide your code so that a correct solution can be made. Your descriptions have been rather vague as to what you're actually doing.